# Find all jars that have red balls and blue balls

Tags: sql, postgresql, relational-division

With this simple query I can find the ids of all jars that contain *either* red balls **or** blue balls:

```
SELECT id FROM "Jars" J
JOIN "Balls" B ON B.jarId = J.jarId
WHERE B.color = 'red' OR B.color = 'blue'
GROUP BY id
```

How can I find the ids of all jars that contain *both* red balls **and** blue balls?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: you should really avoid those dreaded quoted identifiers. They are much more trouble than they are worth it. https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_upper_case_table_or_column_names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a sub-query. You don't even need the JOIN as you only want the IDs of the jars (which is available in the `balls` table)

```
select b.jarid
from balls b
where b.color in ('blue', 'red')
group by b.jarid
having count(*) = 2
```

Note that this will also return balls that have additional colors (e.g. blue, red and yellow).

If you want only those that have **exactly** the colors blue and red, you can use this:

```
select jarid
from balls
group by jarid
having count(*) = 2 
and bool_and(color in ('blue', 'red'))
```

Answer (score 1):

If it’s both you seek, then give this a go:

```
SELECT id
  FROM (
SELECT j.id,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN b.colour = 'red' THEN b.id ELSE NULL END) as reds,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN b.colour = 'blue' THEN b.id ELSE NULL END) as blues
  FROM Jars j INNER JOIN Balls b ON j.jarId = b.jarId
WHERE b.color IN ('red', 'blue')
GROUP BY j.id) tmp
 WHERE tmp.reds > 0 and tmp.blues > 0;
```

Comment: ty, this works, although I was hoping for a simpler answer that doesn't involve a subquery, but maybe that's not possible.